# Панель уведомлений закрывает Activity

Tags: android, react-native

Работаю в React Native. В эмуляторах с разными размерами экрана + на физ. устройстве - такая картина. Наверное дело в коде. В чем может быть причина?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить компонент `<StatusBar />` ([документация](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html))